# How do I apply symbology from a layer to both features and labels with arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I am trying to apply symbology to a layer from another layer. The layer's features (lines) get  symbolized perfectly. My only issue is that the labels do not get any symbology, although the reference symbology layer has symbolized labels. How can I get both the features and lables symbolized?

```
cont5FT = arcpy.mapping.Layer("5FT_Cont") #A feature layer created on the fly
cont5FTSymb = arcpy.mapping.Layer(cont5) #The symbology file
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(cont5FT, cont5FTSymb)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame,cont5FT)
```

Note that I have already tried using a direct link to the symbology layer file. I have also tried UpdateLayer. I tried adding the fields I want to symbolize the labels from but maybe I am doing it wrong. The field to symbolize on is called "Elevation" so would would what I have below be correct?

```
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(cont5FT, cont5FTL.[["VALUE_FIELD","#","Elevation"]])
```

Comment: Labels are not symbols

Comment: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dbb7be9d2c1c491e8c1a067ffd58aea8